# Content Hugging while using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout

in my view controller, there will a collection view and a tableview as shown in the screenshot[image: here]. In some cases, the collection view height has to be zero, and the whole view must contains only tableview. And in some cases, the collection view has to be there and below that tableview has to be placed. I've changed the content hugging priority and so many, but the only thing happening is either the collection view is occupying the whole view or the collection view height is zero but the tableview still starts from middle of the screen. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything with content hugging to accomplish your goal. Give the collection view a height constraint and spacing constraints to the top of the view and to the table view. The table view should have a constraint to the bottom of the view, but no height constraint. Make an IBOutlet to the collection view's height constraint, and set its constant value to 0 when you want the table view to take up the whole screen.